# Find Intersection between Times

Tags: rust, time, iterator

Hello i'm learning Rust at the college and i'm in trouble with an exercise the professor gave us to learn use iterators better.
The exercise says that: you have 2 files, calendar1 and calendar 2 in this format:

```
Content of file calendar1:
08:00 20:00
10:00 11:30
14:00 16:00
```

where the first row is the start hour and the end hour of the workday.
The other rows are the scheduled appointments that are already done for that workday.
Given 2 calendars of the same day, and a number of minutes an appointment has to be taken, you have to write as std output all the possible intervals that are suitable for both the calendars.
Here is an example of output:

```
Content of file cal1:
08:00 20:00
10:00 11:30
14:00 16:00
Content of file cal2:
09:00 18:00
09:30 12:00
13:30 16:30
cargo run -- cal1 cal2 30
09:00 09:30
12:00 13:30
16:30 18:00
```

I've already put some codes and read the files properly and putted them in a struct using the NaiveTime Type to handle hours and minutes

```
#[derive(PartialEq,Clone,Debug)]
pub struct Calendar {
    schedule: Vec<(NaiveTime, NaiveTime)>,
    bounds: (NaiveTime,NaiveTime)
}
```

Now i'm in trouble because the exercise says that, in order to solve this problem, you have to use a complexity of O(M+N) where M and N are the length of the two schedule vectors.
Additionally to solve this the hint is: "use two indipendent iterator, for each list of appointments, and everytime you find a correct "hole" save the interval"
I really don't know how to use the iterators separately because i dont understand how can i check that an interval which, for example, is suitable for the first calendar, at the same time is suitable for the second one. Any help? Thank You

Comment: Are you allowed to assume that the existing appointments in both calendar files are sorted?

Comment: If you can assume that all appointments are non-overlapping and sorted, you can just advance one iterator until its endpoint surpasses the current endpoint in the other iterator, then switch and start advancing the other iterator; keep switching back and forth every time one endpoint surpasses the other.

Comment: Yeah they are supposed to be sorted, but i don't really know how can i swap between iterators in the code, can you give me an example?

Comment: [`swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/mem/fn.swap.html)?